# "How dare I" is natural, correct and polite?

Tags: grammar

I've seen and heard "How dare you".
I am wandering "How dare I" is usally said from native speakers.
If so, is it polite?

If someone is better than me, but I just wanted to let them know.
How dare I suggest that~
If I hurts my girlfriend to not meant
How dare I hurts you, it was an accident.(physical)
or
How dare I hurts you, I didn't meant to say that. I just suddenly upset(mental)
If some native speakers was letting me know something that I had asked and I have to choose one. but I think all seem good. but I choose winner for best like here.
How dare I can't judge you, I just follow ___

Answer (score 3):

"How dare I!" would be an *ironic* (or *sarcastic*) play off of the common expression "How dare you!" used to suggest that the offense you caused was unreasonable or even ridiculous.

For example, suppose my friend is in a bad mood, and she gets angry when I cheerily greet her and compliment her:

> Oh wow.  I'm such a jerk.  First I had the audacity to wish you good morning, and then I made it worse by saying you look really nice today.  **How dare I!**

Otherwise, if you are seriously apologizing for some injury, then there many other expressions you can use:

> **I'm really sorry** that I hurt you.
>
> **It's all my fault** that I hurt you.
>
> **It's terrible** what I did to hurt you.
>
> **I'm so ashamed** of how I hurt you.
>
> I really **messed up**.  **I didn't mean** to hurt you.

And so on.

(Edit) As JBH's comment says, it's possible to use "do I dare" or "dare I ..?" as a [*rhetorical question*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhetorical_question), but this is not suggesting fault as much as questioning courage or capacity.

> Alex: That attractive woman in the cafeteria has been sitting alone every day this week.  **Dare I** go up and ask if she would like some company?
>   Bob:  Go for it, man!

Comment: In support of your answer (I upvoted it): "how dare you!" is a challenge to the listener's authority or ability.  Challenging your own (the speaker's) authority is nonsensical, which is why it is ironic or sarcastic.  If you were to seriously question your own authority, you would use a phrase like "would I dare do that?"